# How to get a youtube video url using youtube dl in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

I want to create a python program that allows me to input search terms and return the url of the first result

```
def search(search):
    #Gets the youtube url of the first result
    return url
```

Something along those lines.
I don't know too much about youtube-dl nor how to implement it into python as I couldn't find much info on how to do this through google.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **python 3.5** then this is pretty simple. I don't know if this works in previous versions of python 3.x.
The result that is returned here is a list of the URLs. So if you want the first result use `search(text)[0]`

```
import subprocess 
def search(text):
    command=['youtube-dl', 'ytsearch:"' + text+'"', '-g']
    result=subprocess.run(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True).stdout.split()
    return result
```

Comment: Doesn't command need to be a list?

Comment: It does not need to be a list if `shell=True`.

Comment: Would this be better as list though? `['youtube-dl ', 'ytsearch:" + text, ' -g']` and not pass `shell=True`? That may mean no need to sanitize?

Comment: Yes that seems to be the better method. I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You must know that every good linux programs has some instructions built-in. To see them, try `youtube-dl --help` or `man youtube-dl`

For your question, from the command line:

```
youtube-dl "ytsearch:Rick Astley" -g
```

No idea about python, but it should be pretty close to the following equivalent in **bash**.

```
#!/bin/bash
youtube-dl "ytsearch: $1" -g
```

just save this in a file, give it the «execution permision» «allow file to be executed as program» or from the command line `chmod +x myprogram`.

Then to call:

```
./myprogram 'rick astley'
```

This will output the first link. The procedure is exactly the same in many languages: python, php, bash (etc). This is a bash script.

Good luck ;)